# Как открыть программу с определенными аргументами?

Tags: java, javafx, cmd, jar

Я хочу сделать мой javafx проект собранный в исполняемый jar файл запускаемый в два клика, без этого:

"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.2\bin\java.exe" --module-path "C:\Program Files\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml "-javaagent:D:\My_files\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3.3\lib\idea_rt.jar=44666:D:\My_files\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3.3\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "D:\My_files\WeatherApp\out\production\WeatherApp;C:\Program Files\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib\src.zip;C:\Program Files\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib\javafx-swt.jar;C:\Program Files\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib\javafx.web.jar;C:\Program Files\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib\javafx.base.jar;C:\Program Files\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib\javafx.fxml.jar;C:\Program Files\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib\javafx.media.jar;C:\Program Files\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib\javafx.swing.jar;C:\Program Files\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib\javafx.controls.jar;C:\Program Files\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib\javafx.graphics.jar;C:\Program Files\json\json-20190722.jar" sample.Main

Пытался открывать командную строку с c# но не работало:
`string command = "<Команда выше>";  System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("cmd.exe", "/C " + command);`

Ошибка: "C:/Program" не является внутренней или внешней командой. С кодом все ок в string command прописывал команду выше с экранированными кавычками. Можно ли как то создать исполняемый файл который запускает мой jar файл с указанными выше аргументами выше?

Comment: ошибка говорит о том, что где-то потеряли кавычку в команде, возможно самую первую, потому что такое бывает, если в пути указать папку, имя которой содержит пробелы, вроде `Program Files`. Посмотрите в отладчике или выведите в консоль значение вашей команды и добейтесь, чтобы оно не отличалось от того, которое привели в качестве примера.

Comment: а для чего создавать исполняемый файл для этого вообще? Создай батник ( .bat )